# How to get type of TKey and TValue given a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to get type of TKey and TValue given a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` type.

eg. If type is `Dictionary<Int32,String>` I want to know how to get 
keyType = typeof(Int32) and 
valueType = typeof(String)

Comment: could you explain why you need that?

Comment: In most *useful* cases, you code already knows the types; either directly (`typeof(int)` / `typeof(string)` in the question), or indirectly via generics - in which case it'll be something like `typeof(TYourKeyType)` / `typeof(TYourValueType)` - do you have `object`?

Comment: I need to construct the Dictionary from Serialized text. As Dictionary is not serializable, we use a custom format. Then when we reconstructing we need types for Key and Value

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Type[] arguments = dictionary.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
Type keyType = arguments[0];
Type valueType = arguments[1];
```

Ref: [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)

Comment: @Mitch: thanks; I can't believe that I missed out on posting a link to the documentation.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding link to your post.

Comment: In DotNet Core it is currently the property `GenericTypeArguments`