# Using Generics to Create a New Object

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, instantiation

I am sorry for multiple questions on the same topic so close together, but I am new to generics, and, although I'm finding it fascinating, it is also proving to be a bit baffling.

I need to use generics to retrieve an entry in a Dictionary, and if the entry does not exist, I need to create it. The Dictionary Key is a String, and the Value is a container class--in this case of type PersonObject, but it could be any type. What I have currently works well, thanks to dtb and p.s.w.g, but I need to somehow make the creation of the new object generic.

```
IDictionary list = source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null) as IDictionary;
if (!list.Contains(property))
    list.Add(property, new HobbyObject());
```

Instead of `new HobbyObject()`, I want to create a new object of the type defined by the Dictionary I am accessing. Can this even be done through reflection, or do I just need to write a large Switch Case for all the possible dictionaries that might be passed in?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It's not a good "smell" to use that much reflection if you're trying to learn generics! If you use the `new()` constructor constraint on a generic parameter, you can create new instances of the type. For example `static bool CreateEntryIfAbsent<TValue>(Dictionary<string, TValue> dict, string key) where TValue : new() { if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) { dict.Add(key, new TValue()); } }`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thank you for the comment, Jeppe. However, I believe this would require passing the type in when I call the method, and I don't have the type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. It sent me a long way towards figuring out the solution, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399710/how-to-get-type-of-tkey-and-tvalue-given-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-type).

For those who are having the same problem, I modified the code so it read:

```
IDictionary list = source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null) as IDictionary;
if (!list.Contains(property))
{
    Type[] arguments = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
    list.Add(property, Activator.CreateInstance(arguments[1]));
}
```

GetGenericArguments() gave me the type of the arguments for the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

```
list.Add(property, Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType());
```

Comment: I like the elegance, but I get an ArgumentException when I try this. I am told that "MapObject.PersonObject" is not of type "MapObject.HobbyObject" and cannot be used in this generic collection. I believe this is because it is getting the type of Source, rather than from the IDictionary, which would be <String, HobbyObject>. Is there a way to access the type of the Value in the Dictionary?

Comment: @Tim - That sounds like an issue of type for the Dictionary. I think you may want to choose a different naming convention than "Object". Moreover, perhaps you should be using an interface that both HobbyObject and PersonObject share, perhaps ICustomObject. This way, you can make your Dictionary be of type `<string,ICustomObject>` and it will support both types.

Comment: try like this (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType)

Comment: @terrybozzio - If you try to cast PersonObject to HobbyObject you will undoubtedly get an invalid casting exception here. Moreover, how is he going to explicitly use the type to cast (Type) when it is discovered during reflection?

Comment: sorry misunderstood,thought he knew the type....my bad ,i meant like ( HobbyObject)Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType()).

Comment: This is actually a concept project, so I can figure out what I am doing before I start to add it to the actual code. When I'm working with new ideas that I don't fully understand, it helps me to make a simplified version. The actual code uses better naming conventions, but the Dictionaries can also be nestled under several classes. My actual goal is to use a String path to drill down through several objects to set a Property. I have this complete, except for the times when I have a list of objects that I need to access one. This is what I am actually doing here.