# C# casting object to class with type argument

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class called Property that stores one value and raises an event if the value changes. There is a different class called Observable that I want to contain a dictionary of properties, and I have an example below.  How can I get the type of a property stored in the dictionary so I can modify the object?

Property Class:

```
public class Property<T>
{
     public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Observable Class:

```
public class Observable
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, object> 
              Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Property<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
        object obj;
        Properties.TryGetValue(name, out obj);
        return (Property<T>) obj;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:  <strike>This is the error I am getting - 
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'ConsoleApplication.Property`1[System.String]'.</strike>

Also, if I could get rid of the Get function and replace it with something that does not require knowing the type that would be much better.

**Update**: Is there a way to get the type  by hashing the name with a type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399710/how-to-get-type-of-tkey-and-tvalue-given-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-type

Comment: Do you want to assume that `Get<T>(...)` will succeed?  What's wrong with the code you've provided?

Comment: that is not what I am asking.  I don't want to get the type of the dictionary's value, I want to get the type of the value within a property.

Comment: So,  you want something that will `return GetType(obj);` ?

Comment: We know that all of the objects in the dictionary are of type Property<T>, but we do not know what T is.  Even when I say what T is an error is thrown.  For example, if I change Property<T> Get<T> to Property<string< Get it still fails.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam The error message you posted is saying that `obj` is of type `string`, and not `Property<T>`

Comment: woops, I accidentally passed in a string instead of a property<string>

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam so did I answer your question?

Comment: halfway. Is there any way to change Get<T>() to just Get()?

Comment: Short answer, it depends.  If you want a strongly-typed object back from `Get()` then you need to specify to C# what type you want.  If you're ok with a `Property<object>` type or like a `Property` type where `Value` would be of type `object`, then yeah it's pretty trivial.

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (for updated post):

> Is there a way to get the type by hashing the name with a type?

Is something like this what you're going for? [dotnetfiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BcbQCS)

```
public interface IProperty
{
    object Value { get; }
    Type TypeOfValue { get; }
}

public class Property : IProperty
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Type TypeOfValue { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return TypeOfValue.FullName + ": " + Value; }
}

public class Observable
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, Property> 
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, Property>();

    // use interface so consumer of your property can't mess with the
    // type or value stored in your dictionary within Observable
    public IProperty Get(string name)
    {
        Property obj;
        if (Properties.TryGetValue(name, out obj)){
            return obj;
        }

        // throw something which makes more sense to you
        throw new ArgumentException(name + " does not exist in the dictionary");
    }

    // sample of how you'd store these properties
    public void Set(string name, object val)
    {
        if (Properties.ContainsKey(name)){
            Properties[name].Value = val;
            Properties[name].TypeOfValue = val.GetType();
        } else {
            Properties[name] = new Property {
                Value = val,
                TypeOfValue = val.GetType()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

It's possible that you're accidently inserting a `string` into your dictionary inside of `Observable` instead of a `Property<string>`, and if so the problem isn't in the code that you've posted and instead wherever you're inserting a `string` instead of a `Property<string>`.

Two solutions if you don't like the invalid cast exception.

## Solution 1: customize the errors your function throws.

If you'd like to keep the signature of `Get<T>(...)` I'd recommend some error handling.  The error you're seeing is because the property in your dictionary is of type `string`, not of type `Property<string>`.  The following code will give you something to work with for more error handling.

```
public class Observable
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, object> 
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Property<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
        object obj;
        if (Properties.TryGetValue(name, out obj)){
            try {
                return (Property<T>) obj;
            } catch(InvalidCastException){
                // throw something which makes more sense to you
                throw new ArgumentException("Could not cast the given object to the desired type");
            }
        }

        // throw something which makes more sense to you
        throw new ArgumentException(name + " does not exist in the dictionary");
    }
}
```

## Solution 2: return a general `object`

```
public class Observable
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, object> 
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object Get(string name)
    {
        object obj;
        if (Properties.TryGetValue(name, out obj)){
            return obj;
        }

        // or do whatever you want when the given key doesn't exist.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexers may solve your problem without using additional constructs. 
Have a look if you areI'm not sure if I got you clear, but I'll try to help )
As for me the question may be rephrased as follows.
Is it possible to determine most specific type of the upcasted type.

Here is a code which may help you

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int salary { get; set; }

}

public class Manager : Employee
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Manager man = new Manager();
        System.Object emp = (object) man;
        Console.WriteLine(emp.GetType());
    }
}
```

The output of the WriteLine operation is "Project_Name".Manager so you can see what type was originally allocated in memory. not familiar with them.